# iPhone UIViewController init method not being called

Tags: iphone

I am very new to iPhone programming and am running into a little bit of weirdness. For the following class, the init method just never gets called -- I have an NSLog function which should tell me when init is executed. Here's the relevant code:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (id) init
{
    NSLog(@"init invoked");
    return self;
}
@end
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong -- if anything? Hopefully I provided enough information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the view coming up? Use these methods for additional initialization:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //...
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view.
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //..
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Though it leaves a little sour taste in my mouth to see some inconsistencies in Obj-C on iPhone. Oh well.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using a Storyboard, `initWithCoder:` will be called. Reference document says:

> If your app uses a storyboard to define a view controller and its
>   associated views, your app never initializes objects of that class
>   directly. Instead, view controllers are either instantiated by the
>   storyboard—either automatically by iOS when a segue is triggered or
>   programmatically when your app calls the storyboard object’s
>   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method. When instantiating a
>   view controller from a storyboard, iOS initializes the new view
>   controller by calling its initWithCoder: method instead. iOS
>   automatically sets the nibName property to a nib file stored inside
>   the storyboard.

The `initWithCoder:` method isn't part of the default template of a .m file, so you have to add yourself in your UIViewController subclass:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        NSLog(@"Was called...");
    }

    return self;
}
```

There is no need to delete `initWithNibName:bundle:` from your code, but it won't be called anyway.

Comment: could you elaborate on this? Im using a viewController of subclass MyController which I have set the viewcontroller I made in storyboard to. However, in my .m file, I only see a initWithNibName method and no initWithCoder method. Am i supposed to delete initWithNibName and put in initWithCoder or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: There is no need to delete initWithNibName. Just add the initWithCoder (this method isn't in the default template for a .m file). I've changed my answer to denote this.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my edit, no idea why it was rejected or what they think self is going to be without the [super init] Grrr. Cheers :)

Comment: I don't know why too. Thanks for pointing that. I really forgot. :)

Answer (score 23):

You are probably creating your view controller from a NIB file. So, instead of calling "init" message, this is the one creator message being called:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Try if that is the one being called. What Sean said is true. You could use those messages to accomplish similar things.

Good luck.

Comment: Right after I posted my comment above, I realized why init wasn't being called... :P

Comment: The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller **programmatically** and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2):

Refer 'designated initializer' in reference document too.

Answer (score 2):

But, a UI component has sometimes severals init* methods, do we need to override all these methods in order to do some init. stuff?

Comment: Seems like you only have to override the "designated initializer".  The only way to find out which init* method this is is via the documentation.