# Refresh table from another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers one of them (`ViewController`) has a table called `tableView`.

I would like to refresh this table from my other view controller (`pageView`).

I have tried this in the `pageView`:

```
ViewController*refresh;
[refresh.tableView reloadData];
```

But this is not working.

The connecting segue between the two view controllers is a push segue

What should I do? Should I do it through a storyboard segue?

Comment: When you first `init` your controller, do it with a singleton.  Then, from anywhere you can call [[Controller sharedInstance].tableView reloadData], assuming tableView is a public property.

Comment: What is happening in pageView? Is page view retrieving data and pushing the new data to the array which is used to display your tableView? Is page view a view? NSNotification should work fine, as I have a similar implementation. Unless you are trying to trigger your NSNotification from pageView without tableView being active at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Option 1**

@Class2

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldRefresh; // in .h file

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated // in .m file
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (_shouldRefresh) [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

@Class1

```
// Add this in any method where you want it to refresh and push to view
ClassTwoController *viewController = [[ClassTwoController alloc] init];
[viewController setShouldRefresh:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

---

***UPDATE:**

**Option 2**

@Class 2

```
// Add this line in viewDidLoad in same class you want the tableView to refresh
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshTableWithNotification:) name:@"RefreshTable" object:nil];

// Add this method just beneath viewDidLoad:
- (void)refreshTableWithNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

@Class1

```
// Call this when ever you want to refresh the tableView in Class2
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefreshTable" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Comment: can I do this without having to re-create the `ClassTwoController` ? as I have a startup animation that I don't want to happen twice!

Comment: well yes you dont have to re-allocate, if its a global variable, you can just use the following: [self.viewController setShouldRefresh:YES];

Comment: no I mean how can I do this `ClassTwoController *viewController = [[ClassTwoController alloc] init];` without "re creating it"

Comment: Thats 1 way, another way is to remove data when the view disappeared, then reload new data when view will appear. Or you can add `NSNotificationCenter` to send notifications that the table should reload due to new data, once the notification has been received the table will reload.

Comment: I dont understand by recreating it, youre just allocating memory to it, if it is already allocated (created) then the above code will work. Have you even tried it? lol

Comment: The viewController is refreshing as well as the table (i.e re creating it) I just want the table to refresh.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong as I know this works and I'm using it as well, and it got most upvotes in this thread, what does that tell you?

Answer (score 3):

/* Add this line in viewDidLoad method in ViewController (by using this line you are adding notification observer to ViewController class) */

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTableview:) name:@"ReloadTableview" object:nil];
```

/* Add this method in ViewController class(this method call when you post notification in pageView) */

```
- (void)reloadTableview:(NSNotification *)notif
{
     [tableView reloadData];
}
```

/* add this line when/where you want to refresh your (this line post notification which added in ViewController) */

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadTableview" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

If second view controller is already loaded then you can use NSNotification in firstviewcontroller. This notification will invoke a method in second view controller. In this method write a code to reload a tableview.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to reload a table view that exists in the previous view controller of your navigation stack. If so, you can access it through the navigation controller's `viewControllers` property.

```
NSUInteger indexOfTableController = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2;
ViewController *tableController = (ViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexOfTableController];
[tableController.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: @Maximilian Do you get some sort of error? Is my assumption about your view controller hierarchy correct?

Comment: @Maximilian Does the table update if you reload the data on the `ViewController`'s (the one with the table view) `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: is that just this `-(void)viewDidAppear{}` in the `ViewController` ?

Comment: `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { [super viewWillAppear:animated]; [self.tableView reloadData];}`

Comment: Yeah, still nothing happens when coming back from a push segue. I might create a new segue!

Comment: @Maximilian make sure that you indeed update your data source as well

Comment: Check if your array is updated which is used to fill the tableView.

Comment: That is not going to work because reloaddata needs to execute in the ViewController (Parent) that owns the tableview - it is not just a simple function but a delegate method that calls all your other overridden tableviewmethods like cellForRowAtIndexPath. You need to build a public method that contains the reload data command and call that method from the other view controller. command

Answer (score 1):

Most often this happens because you're not initializing the reference to your second controller properly and it stays nil. Has to be something like this.

```
@implementation
{
    ViewController *refresh;
}

- (void) openNewController
{
    refresh = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:refresh animated:true];
}

- (void) refreshNewController 
{
    [refresh.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: this just reverts to the first ViewController and then it goes black!

Answer (score 1):

Okay for sake of example lets call the previous ViewController VC1 and the current ViewController VC2.

So you do a push segue from VC1 to VC2. What you could do is: pass a reference of the TableView to VC2 during the segue. So you would create a public UITableView tblView variable in VC2 and then in VC1 implement the prepareForSegue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Segue_Identifier_From_StoryBoard"])
    {
        // get your destination view controller
        VC2 *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];

        vc2.tblView = TableView;
    }
}
```

Then in VC2, you could just call `[tblView reloadData];`

Just make sure you nil the tblView reference once you are done with VC2.

Comment: How do you mean "make sure you nil the tblView"?

Answer (score 1):

In ViewController1 :

```
> Create property for UITableview with nonatomic and retain
> Now Create table Object.
```

In ViewController2.m:

```
ViewController1 *objV1 = [ViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName....];   

[objV1.yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: But the table is not a nib? Can I not do innit?

Comment: See this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188387/uiviewcontroller-init-vs-initwithnibnamebundle]

Comment: If you alloc/init vc1, you'll create another instance of controller so it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the adress of viewcontroller.tableview and refresh.tableView and i think they would be not the same;
you can make singleton for viewcontroller and then invoke for example

```
viewcontroller *vc = [viewcontroller sharedInstance];
[[vc tableview] reloadData];
```

Comment: I get the error: `No known class method for selector 'sharedInstance'`

Answer (score 1):

In your  pageView create a method

```
-(void) reloadVCController{

  ViewController*vc=[[ViewController alloc]init]];
    [vc.tableview reloadData;
}
```

And use it where you want to call it

```
[self reloadVCController];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewController*refresh;
[refresh.tableView reloadData];
```

By seeing the above code you are not assigning your `ViewController instance` to `refresh`. When executing `reloadData()` your `refresh` will be nil so obviously it won't react to any action.

```
ViewController*refresh = originalInstance; //assign your original instance here
    [refresh.tableView reloadData];
```

this would work and the main point to be noted here is your refresh `viewcontroller` should be the top most instance in stack because any UI operation should happen in main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSnotification center add observer in that view controller and write method for reload table.
[self.tableView reloadData];
And from current view post notify that observer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have tried all the answers, **make sure that before reloading the tableView, the dataSource is actually updated** with new/additional/ content.

Answer (score 1):

Reloaddata needs to execute within the parentviewcontroller because it invokes the tableview delegate methods to reload the table such as CellForRowAtIndexpath, and many more.
 This means you need to define a public method in the parentviewcontroller that will contain the reloaddata command and call it from the child view controller.

public Method:

Parentviewcontroller.h

```
@interface 

 -(void) reloadTable:(id) sender;
```

parentviewcontroller.m

```
@implementation

- (void) reloadTable:(id) sender {
   [self.tableview reloaddata];
   return;
 }
```

childviewcontroller.h

```
 #import parentviewcontroller.h
  @class parentviewController 
  @interface childviewcontroller :UIViewController (or UITableViewController)

  @property (nonatomic, strong) parentViewController *parent;
```

childviewController.m

```
@implementation  
 @synthesize parent; 

 /*  Note the parent instance is passed from the parent to the child view controller,      
 it is not allocated and initialised in the child controller -  many ways to do this 
 depending on coding style  */

/* after updating the data */   

 [parent reloadTable];
```

Comment: You should have weak reference to parent or you will create retain cycle(you can break it manually, but why do it).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you **refresh** controller view is not loaded. So, **reloadTable** message simply goes to nil. You can force a View Controller to load its view by calling **view getter**:

```
[viewController view];
```

So check if your **tableView** is nil and if it is, initialise it with described method.

Answer (score 1):

As a make-up answer to emotality's:

If you want to skip the start-up animation, just simply set a bool property in your `ClassTwoController` to check if it's first time loading this view

ClassTwoController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL notFirstTimeRun;
```

ClassTwoController.m:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated // in .m file
{
    if(self.notFirstTimeRun) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
         [self playStartUpAnime];
    }
}

 -(void)playStartUpAnimation // in .m file
{
    //Place your codes for animation here
}
```

in your `ClassOneController`.m initialise it with the check bool:

```
ClassTwoController *viewController = [[ClassTwoController alloc] init];
viewController.notFirstTimeRun = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have parent-child relationship you can add weak property to child viewcontroller like this

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) ParentViewController *parentController;
```

Then when you need to reload table you just call `[parentController.tableView reloadData]`

Other way would be using NSNotificationCenter. In controller you want to reload table you should subscribe to notification(`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver...]`) and implement selector you supply to this method. In another controller you should post notification with that name.

Also you can just refresh on viewWillAppear if it suits your needs.