# App with TabBar navigation control and TableView method didselectrowatindexpath

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview, detailview

I'm newbie in iOS development, and have a problem with my application. I have implemented a tabbar navigation and a TableView, but when call method didselectrowatindexpath i dont see the detailView linked. This is the code of my app:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"ciao");
    // UITableViewStyleGrouped table view style will cause the table have a textured background 
    // and each section will be separated from the other ones.
    controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
                                        //initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped 
                                        //andDvdData:[dao libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    controller.title = [[dao libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}

#import "DetailViewController.h" 

@interface ListItemsTableView : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet    UITableView     *myTableView;
    Dfetch                      *dao;
    DetailViewController        *controller;

}
```

Comment: Is data is populating? have you set myTableView.delegate=self?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the right initializer for UIViewController.

The one you're expected to use is [`[UIViewController initWithNibName: bundle:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a) (documentation at Apple linked for you).

I suspect your "controller" object is NULL.

Comment: if he called `alloc` and `init` then 'controller' can not be as `nil`.

Comment: well... it might not be NULL but the view controller probably isn't set up properly if one isn't using the designated initializer.  [Here is a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772182/iphone-uiviewcontroller-init-method-not-being-called).